# how to pass variable with value from one robot file to another robot file in robot frame work

Tags: robotframework

Test 1.robot

```
*** Variables ***
${node}         babitha

*** Test Cases ***
A Test Case
     Log To Console    ${node}
```

Test 2.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Resource  C:\Users\2013\Desktop\Test 1.robot


*** Test Cases ***
A Test Case
     Log To Console    ${node}
```

Trying to print babitha on console when i am running Test 2.robot file

Answer (score 2):

A resource file cannot contain `*** Test Cases ***` section - if you try to run your sample the framework will probably produce an error with such message.

If you want to use a variable from one suite in another, then in the initial one you declare it it as such with the [`Set Global Variable` keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-set-test-suite-global-variable-keywords):

```
Set Global Variable    ${node}    # you can reassign its value here, or leave to the previously set
```

This has one caveat though - you must be sure the setter is going to be called before the case that will try to use it (naturally) - otherwise, it will not be defined for it.

---

An alternative is to store the variable in a 3rd file (a resource one) and import it in the suites that need it.

---

And another alternative is to pass it with `--variable node:babitha` in the command line when running the tests - thus it will be globally available from the start, and all cases will be able to access it (and modify, through the `Set Global Variable`).

Answer (score 0):

If more .robot files have to share some variable(s), it's better to keep these variables in a separate file (and folder), I'd suggest similar structure:

```
.
|__Resources
|__Tests
```

In `Resources/`, you will have a file I'll call `config.py`:

```
node = "babitha"
```

The last step you need is to load the config file in both of your test suites:

**Tests/Test 1.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    ../Resources/config.py

*** Test Cases ***
A Test Case
     Log To Console    ${node}
```

**Tests/Test 2.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    ../Resources/config.py

*** Test Cases ***
A Test Case
     Log To Console    ${node}
```

One remark at the end:

You used an absolute path `C:\Users\2013\Desktop\Test 1.robot`, try to avoid that, if someone else clones your project, it will likely break on their environment

Comment: Thank you so much,but that value of that node will change for every test cases (that variable is in for loop)

Comment: Then you need to include it in your question. I have no idea about your context and requirements. I can only answer what I know.